# Odoo 10 is not backing up DB in PostgreSQL 9.5. Shows "SQL state: 22008. Timestamp out of range on account_bank_statement_line."

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, odoo-10, postgresql-9.5, pg-dump

At our company we had a DB crash a few days ago due to hardware reasons. We recovered from that but since then we're having this following error every time we try to back up our DB.

```
pg_dump: ERROR:  timestamp out of range
pg_dump: SQL command to dump the contents of table "account_bank_statement_line"
```

The error is in "account_bank_statement_line" table, where we have 5 rows created with only the 'create_date' column has a date of year 4855(!!!!), the rest of the columns have null value, even the id (primary key). We can't even delete or update those rows using pgAdmin 4 or PostgreSQL terminal.

**We're in a very risky stage right now with no back up of few days of retail sales. Any hints at least would be very highly appreciated.**

Comment: While pg_dump is a way to do backups, you should consider doing physical backups rather than logical using pg_basebackup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if the data are important, hire a specialist.

Second, run your `pg_dump` with the option `--exclude-table=account_bank_statement_line` so that you at least have a backup of the rest of your database.

The next thing you should do is to stop the database and take a cold backup of all the files. That way you have something to go back to if you mess up.

The key point to proceed is to find out the `ctid`s (physical addresses) of the problematic rows. Then you can use that to delete the rows.

You can approach that by running queries like

```
SELECT create_date FROM account_bank_statement_line
WHERE ctid < '(42,0)';
```

and try to find the `ctid`s where you get an error. Once you have found a row where the following falls over:

```
SELECT * FROM account_bank_statement_line
WHERE ctid = '(42,14)';
```

you can delete the row by its `ctid`.

Once you are done, take a `pg_dumpall` of the database cluster, create a new one and restore the dump. It is dangerous to continue working with a cluster that has experienced corruption, because corruption can remain unseen and spread.

Comment: Thank you so much! 
We got the db backup working in another way though, will be posting that here as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know what we did might not be the most technically advanced, but it solved our issue. We consulted a few experts and what we did was:

- migrated all the data to a new table (account_bank_statement_line2), this transferred all the rows that had valid data.
- Then we deleted the "account_bank_statement_line" table and
- renamed the new table to "account_bank_statement_line".
- After that we could DROP the table.

Then the db backup ran smoothly like always.

Hope this helps anyone who's in deep trouble like us. Cheers!